# Pandas groupby result into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I'm working on a data that contains duplicates. If "similarity_index" of the row is equal to another row, that means they are duplicates. I'm trying to merge this duplicates.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
           ad    soyad similarity_index
0       hakan  özdemir                0
1       hasan    yaman                1
2        naci    şenli                2
3      naciye      şen                2
4       osman    uygur                3
5        elif    sözen                4
6        irem   derici                5
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
test_df.set_index("similarity_index").sort_index()
```

Here is the output:

```
                          ad    soyad
similarity_index                     
0                      hakan  özdemir
0                 hakan utku  özdemir
1                      hasan    yaman
2                       naci    şenli
2                     naciye      şen
3                      osman    uygur
4                       elif    sözen
5                       irem   derici
5                       irem   delici
6                       hako  özdemir
```

Here is what I want:

```
                          ad    soyad
similarity_index                     
0                      hakan  özdemir
                  hakan utku  özdemir
1                      hasan    yaman
2                       naci    şenli
                      naciye      şen
3                      osman    uygur
4                       elif    sözen
5                       irem   derici
                        irem   delici
6                       hako  özdemir
```

With this I'm trying to accomplish selecting duplicate rows with the same index. I tried `groupby()` and `pivot_table()`. But I couldn't find a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually a customized function of the default indexing function of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
def index_duplicates_with_same_index(df, index, column_name):
    return df[df[column_name]==index]
df = pd.DataFrame([['hakan',  'özdemir', 0], ['hasan',  'yaman', 1],['naci',  'şenli', 2],['naciye',  'şen', 2]], columns = ['ad','soyad','similarity_index'])
print(df)
```

[image]

```
print(index_duplicates_with_same_index(df, 2, 'similarity_index'))
```

[image]